# What is the difference between the utility with the ex-post or the ex-ante utility function?

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, utility, bayesian-game, information

What is the difference of the ex-post utility function of the utility function. For example in [Bergemann and Morris (2019)](https://elischolar.library.yale.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3544&context=cowles-discussion-paper-series) the utility function is defined as an ex-post utility function. Check in page $7$. Is this assumption critical? If it was not mentioned, could this change anything?

I can not understand what is the difference between the utility with the ex-post or the ex-ante utility function. Could anyone shed some light to the topic?

Comment: All it means is that you know the specifiv  value only after action profiles and states of nature are realized. If the word confuses you, ignore it.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker thanks...it makes sense...It was just the word, that confused me, but it is so simple to understand what it is after all....